# Python не видит модуль Pillow

Tags: python-3.x

Такая ситуация. Решил попробовать библиотеку Pillow. Установил в нужной папке через powershell.
Python3.8

```
pip install pillow
```

После этого взял пример работы с ней

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('RGBA', (200, 200), 'white')    
idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

idraw.rectangle((10, 10, 100, 100), fill='blue')

img.save('rectangle.png')
```

Почему то вылезает следующая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 1, in <module>
from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Помогите. Попробовал по-моему всё. (Только с этим модулем такая проблема)

Comment: А установил ли? Pillow с заглавной буквы должно быть.

Comment: в папке со скриптом проверь чтобы небыло pillow.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была исправлена магическим образом. Я просто изменил расположение файла переместив его из папки на рабочий стол. Теперь этот вопрос выглядит глупо.

Comment: А в какой папке до этого был скрипт?

Comment: Он был в по пути d:/bot

Comment: Меня удивляет то что это произошло только с этим модулем. Т. к для проекта который я делаю я использую много модулей. С ними не было никаких пробоем

Answer (score 0):

попробуй скачать от сюда https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pykinsol
заходишь в директорию со скаченным файлом под твою систему и пишешь в cmd  pip install pillow
и пробуй

Comment: Это не помогло. Он всё равно не может найти модуль с таким именем.

Comment: При этом через  `pip freeze` его показывает.